# Find Major network vslm

Tags: ip, ipv4, subnet, ip-address

Im a bit lost with this question. In order to get proceed with the vslm i need to find the Major network of this subnet 121.118.40.0 /19.
For me the major network is 121.118.32.0/19, but when I run vslm calculator I get as major network 121.118.0.0/16....how is this possible?

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 3):

> i need to find the Major network of this subnet 121.118.40.0 /19.

Actually, `121.118.40.0 /19` is *not* a subnet, it is the 2048th host address on the `121.118.32.0/19` network. You, apparently have a crappy calculator.

You seem to have correctly figured the network for that address and mask. This [two-part answer](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/a/53994/8499) explains about how to calculate the network.